# picking a base for the gram schmidt process with this inner product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials

first let me start by apologizing if this question has been asked before, but i've never studied math in english and am lacking the language to formulate a proper search string, and now onto the question:

let $V$ be a vector space of the real polynomials  where the following is true:
$f(-1)=f(1)=0$

the inner product is defined as: $\langle f, g \rangle = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx$

i need to find a orthonormal base for $V$. i can't seem to figure out how to use `f(-1)=f(1)=0` some one told me that it is supposed to help me pick a base, but i don't see how, any sort of hint/solution would be greatly appreciated

note: i found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069424/applying-gram-schmidt-process-to-a-set-of-vectors-to-find-first-three-polynomial) question which seems to be almost identical but without $f(-1)=f(1)=0$

Comment: The vector space of these polynomials is the set of polynomials of the form $((x^2-1)P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is any polynomial.

Comment: @JeanMarie im sorry, i don't know what that means

Comment: What @JeanMarie meant is the following: Let $q(x)$ be a real polynomial such that $q(-1)= q(1) =0$. Then $(x+1)/q(x)$ and $(x-1)/q(x)$, in particular $(x^2 -1)/ q(x)$ (why?). Thus, one can write $q(x) = (x^2-1)p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is another real polynomial.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano unfortunately, i still don't understand how this helps me pick a base. should i attempt to pick things that are divisible by $q(x)$ ?

Comment: Do you know a basis for the whole space of real polynomials? Then you can express $p(x)$ in terms of this basis and write $q(x) = (x^2-1)p(x)$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano if my base is {$1$,$x$,$x^{2}$,$x^{3}$} do i just multiply them by $(x^2 - 1)$ ? that cant be right.. do i try to represent them as $(x^2 - 1)$ times something = my base members? (i don't actaully know much calculus, this is a particularly bothersome question in an algebra course)

Comment: @Nullman that's right, the basis is $(x^2-1).1, (x^2-1).x, (x^2-1).x^2, ...$

Comment: @JeanMarie i think i'm misunderstanding something basic here. lets say i want to preform $⟨f,f⟩$ on $x^2 - 1$ dont i just end up with a more complex expression then i would have if i did $⟨1,1⟩$ ?